# MeshRegion: How to take out a subregion

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, mesh

I have this application at hand: I need to find the Voronoi Regions of a finite set of point and then i have to find the center of mass of each of these Voronoi regions for a given mass distribution. The Voronoi regions can be constructed through VoronoiMesh function, simple enough. But from this MeshRegion object I want to select individual cells and make each a MeshRegion so that I can pass it on to NIntegrate that computes the center of mass. How to do this selection and construction of meshregions out of the cells?

Comment: Take a look at `MeshPrimitives`.

Comment: that just returns a list of polygons. how do i make say each individual polygon into a new MeshRegion?

Comment: You can extract coordinates of `MeshRegion` with `MeshCoordinates`, and construct a new mesh regions with each individual cell in `MeshCells` list from it, but that's a bit excessive. Points, lines, polygons and three-dimensional regions provided by `MeshPrimitives` should be directly usable in symbolic regions computation, such as a specification of region of integration using `Element`.

Comment: @kirma is right: the primitives returned by `MeshPrimitives` can be used directly in further computation. However, if you absolutely positively have to have mesh regions, you can use `DiscretizeRegion`. For example if vm is the output of `VoronoiMesh`, then `DiscretizeRegion /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]` will give you a list of mesh regions corresponding to the cells of the Voronoi tessellation.

Comment: @MarcoB I wonder if these regions are precisely the same as listed by `MeshPrimitives`, or if they can differ (may, for instance be split to multiple components, etc.)...

Comment: @kirma Since the original regions are polygons more complex than triangles, they are definitely going to be split into smaller components (i.e. triangular cells). That shouldn't affect the integration though. Also, you may be able to minimize the number of mesh cells by specifying a high `MaxCellMeasure` value for `DiscretizeRegion`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Voronoi mesh is composed of convex polygons. If you can assume that the density of each mesh cell is uniform, then the center of mass corresponds to the centroid of the polygon. If that's the case, you can use `RegionCentroid` to determine the centroid of a geometrical region.

Generate a mesh from random points:

```
SeedRandom[25]
vm = VoronoiMesh@(pts = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {10, 2}]);
Show[vm, Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image: Voronoi diagram]

Extract the graphics primitives corresponding to each mesh cell:

```
primitives = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]
```

> ```
> {Polygon[{{40.3579, 40.0372}, {15.2559, 39.468},
>             {5.3674, 0.590703}, {34.8597, 19.3549}}], 
>    Polygon[{{49.1342, 45.0309}, {73.7966, -7.1283},
>             {96.6581, 62.1957}, {58.2447, 59.6855}}], <...> }
> ```

Calculate the position of the centroids:

```
RegionCentroid /@ primitives

(* Out:
{{22.5691, 24.3983}, {72.383, 36.8604}, {22.599, -3.52749}, {24.7894, 94.0762}, 
 {-7.97345, 79.5994}, {97.9175, 18.2534}, {-6.58202, 17.9851}, {79.3346, 91.7492}, 
 {52.4768, 8.87061}, {28.6069, 54.4739}}
*)
```

Show them on the diagram:

```
Graphics[{
   (* Generating points *)
   PointSize[0.01], Black, Point@pts,
   (* Voronoi cells *)
   EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], primitives,
   (* centroids *)
   PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@centroids
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If you **still need to use integration** (e.g. your density is non-uniform), you can use the `Polygon` regions directly as integration domains.

For instance, the following calculates the area of each primitive:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ #] & /@ primitives

(* Out:
{738.533, 1721.1, 1018.74, 2155.02, 1844.03, 2324.13, 1808.98, 3795.38,
 1484.51, 1309.37}
*)
```

Note that the same result could have been obtained using [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html), or [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html).

Comment: Thanks MarcoB. I did the same. Now another thing, which I think is actually a bigger problem. The outermost cells are actually unbounded regions (they extend to the entire plane. I have non-uniform mass density. How can I modify the outermost polygons/cells/regions so that NIntegrate treats them as unbounded,

Comment: @Iconoclast What would you want to do with the unbounded cell?

Comment: I am trying to run the Loyd-Max algorithm for building a Vector Quantizer for a 2D Gaussian dsistribution. The Gaussian distribution is the mass density in my case and is unbounded. The algorithm is simple. first pick N random points. Build a Voronoi Regions for those points, find the center of mass of those regions and make these center of masses the starting new points and repeat until convergence. the problem is that the points for the outer regions do not seem to converge as they are unbounded.

Comment: @Iconoclast, why not use `ConvexHullMesh[]` to pick out the unbounded regions, then?

Comment: I dont understand. ConvexHullMesh[] still gives bounded regions.... I want to integrate over unbounded domain/region.